# drop rows having more than one values from two columns using python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| A | CT |
| A | T |
| ATT | T |

I want to drop two rows from two columns having more than one character such as (ATT and CT) rows and count only the remaining rows. Please guide me on how to code using python.

The expected output

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| A | T |

Comment: What are these rows in? A dataframe? A CSV file? A database? Please [edit] more information into your question and add the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

you can use lambda function to go through each row and check if true show

Code:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: len(x.ColA)<=1 and len(x.ColB)<=1, axis=1)]
```

**Or** by converting list to str and select only less than 2

```
df[df.T.apply(lambda x: len(''.join(x))<3)] #len(AT)<3
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach using [`numpy.char.str_len`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.char.str_len.html):

```
mask = (np.char.str_len(df.to_numpy("str")) <= 1).all(1)
res = df[mask]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  Column_A Column_B
1        A        T
```

The first step:

```
(np.char.str_len(df.to_numpy("str")) <= 1)
```

creates a boolean matrix:

```
[[ True False]
 [ True  True]
 [False  True]]
```

from that matrix the function [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) *find* the *rows* where *all* the values are `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: len("".join(x)) == len(x), axis=1)]
```